# How to bind TextBoxes to an ObservableCollection in an ItemsControl with UniformGrid

Tags: wpf, binding, textbox, observablecollection, uniformgrid

If in WPF I have this code:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

...
...

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<String> myMatrixData = new ObservableCollection<String>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            myMatrixData.Add("Test");

        myMatrix.ItemsSource = myMatrixData;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Cell00.Text = myMatrixData[0];
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
...
...
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="myMatrix">
            <ItemsControl.Resources>

            </ItemsControl.Resources>

            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <!-- specify the panel that is the container for the items -->
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Rows="10" Columns="10" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <!-- specify the template used to render each item -->
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String[]}">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=., UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <Button Content="Read cell 0/0" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Cell00"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I just want to reflect the elements in the `ObservableCollection myMatrixData` to be reflected in a `UniformGrid`-style `ItemsControl` named `myMatrix`. Changing the text in the first cell and pressing the button reveals that this doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where is your property change notification?

Comment: Where are the bindings?

Comment: I would suspect property change notifications are handled in the ObservableCollection? Binding is here: "<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=. ..."

Comment: No, you have to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged or use one of many MVVM frameworks...

Comment: I'm starting to get the collection separated from the property in my head...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObservableCollection<string>` does not update changes to the `string` because `string` itself does not implement `INotifypropertyChanged`

try createing a simple model for your collection

Example:

```
private ObservableCollection<Matrix> _myMatrix = new ObservableCollection<Matrix>();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        MyMatrix.Add(new Matrix { Value = "Test" + i });
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<Matrix> MyMatrix
{
    get { return _myMatrix; }
    set { _myMatrix = value; }
}

.......


public class Matrix : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _value;
    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Value"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication9"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="UI">
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="myMatrix" ItemsSource="{Binding MyMatrix}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <!-- specify the panel that is the container for the items -->
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Rows="10" Columns="10" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <!-- specify the template used to render each item -->
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Matrix}">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <Button Content="Read cell 0/0" Click="Button_Click_1" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="Cell00" />
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Somehow I considered ObservableCollection as an 'all inclusiv' class, because the transfer from the source worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found this pretty useful with making the binding work with NotifyPropertyChanged and also commands

[wpf-mvvm-inotifypropertychanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285377/wpf-mvvm-inotifypropertychanged-implementation-model-or-viewmodel)

[Implementing the MVVM Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx)

[WPF/MVVM Quick Start Tutorial --- Super Handy This One](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial)

Comment: Thanks, two of them I didn't already read. I surely want to apply the M-V-VM pattern and have dozens of tutorials now, I just omitted M-V-VM for clarities sake here. The last step will be to strip the ObservableCollection from the Strings in the data model and work with INotify...